# why markers are not plotted in map using react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using this map to plot my points

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps

I am not able to show plot points
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-wozniak-kq9uu

```
<Marker
          key={park.trackingId}
          position={{
            lat: park.endPoint.coordinates[1],
            lng: park.endPoint.coordinates[0]
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedPark(park);
          }}
```

Comment: They are there. Just zoom out and look at north of Finland.

Comment: I think it will show three markers..!!

Comment: All three of them there. Just two of them overlapping. Also why are you yelling at me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually has markers, but it is zoomed-out, I think you interchanged the position also, try to change it to:

```
      <Marker
          key={park.trackingId}
          position={{
            lat: park.endPoint.coordinates[0],
            lng: park.endPoint.coordinates[1]
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            setSelectedPark(park);
          }}
        />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to help...!